# Multi text classification problem with more than 2000 class

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, data-preprocessing

I'm working in a project with more than 2000 class with 230000 rows , The dataset consists of two columns product name and category name. I applied NLP techniques to vectorize the texts and used linear svm to predict the category of the products and I reached a training accuracy of 92 % and 84% on testing.The problem here is that I have imbalanced classes as some categories have 30000 product or more and some have 200 or 1000 or 10000 product so I tried to over sample the minor classes to the majority class but it gives me an error so is oversampling the minor classes is the right technique or should I try something else? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqDYZ.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do **not** post screenshots of code or error messages, see how to create a [mre].

Comment: To clarify; just because you got a *coding* error, you wonder if SMOTE is appropriate for your case or not?

Comment: No , I didn't post because I got a coding error, I post because to know if the concept is acceptable or not

Comment: If so, the screenshot is just irrelevant clutter; plus, this is not a *programming* question, hence it is off-topic here - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 0):

SMOTE is a good starting. A couple of the other things that you can try a [penalization model](https://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/) there is also a [imbalanced learn module](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/07/10-techniques-to-deal-with-class-imbalance-in-machine-learning/) in python.
Or you can try [upweighting](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/data-prep/construct/sampling-splitting/imbalanced-data)
Try looking around on the internet for other options too. machinelearningmastery.com is a good place to get started on imbalanced data

Comment: Kindly refrain from answering off-topic questions, as advised in the [community guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions). Here, apart from the question lacking details (screenshots are not admissible here), the OP are not even posing a well-defined question, confounding the *coding* error they get with SMOTE being appropriate for their case or not (which, BTW, not being about *programming*, is also off-topic here).